# WatchKit App Icon Missing from Home Screen

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit

My Apple Watch app has been rejected by the App Store because the icon does not appear on the watch home screen. I do not see any icons at all in the simulator and the companion app on the iPhone simulator has my app selected to appear on the watch and has an icon.

Every Apple Watch icon is provided in images.xcassets which exists for the main iPhone app, WatchKit extension and the WatchKit App.

Please tell me how I can find out what the problem is.

These are the icons in my WatchKit app bundle.

[image: Icons in my WatchKit app bundle]

I have also uploaded a 1024x1024 icon to iTunes Connect as required.

My attributes inspector shows this for Images.xcassets for my WatchKit App.

[image]

I am still looking for the Image Set setting screen.

In the WatchKit app Info.plist, there is only one icon under Icon files, icon40.png.

Found the Image Set which is now this.

[image]

I am actually using an AppIcon image set with these settings

[image]

The 40pt image is an 80x80 PNG and the 44pt an 88x88 PNG. The WatchKit target in the AppIcon setting points to my iPhone app Images.xcassets which has these icons.

Will resubmit to the App Store now with this info and hope for the best.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are not assigning your icon to your Target.

You should not make an individual icon set for each size of icon, but make one icon set, of type **AppIcon**.

First, make an AppIcon in your `images.xcassets`, by right clicking in the left pane and choosing **New App Icon**:

[image]

Add your images, and in the properties, choose your watch kit app as **Target Membership**:

[image]

Then go to your Watch App Target and assign this AppIcon as **Apps Icons Source**:

[image]

Comment: I think this must be it and will let you know if my app is accepted. What a rookie mistake I made!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the icon is included in the WatchKit app bundle (not extension) and that it meets all of the criteria Apple has set and make sure they are assigned to your current target.

**Apple may be requiring these to be in the xcassets.**

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Images.html
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/watch/

The system will resize your icon for the App Store and apply a circular mask. Do not upload a circular icon. Keep the design simple and note that elements on the outer edges will be obscured by the circular mask. Avoid using black in the background of your icon to keep it from blending in to the black Apple Watch home screen.

*1024 x1024 pixels
72 dpi, RGB, flattened, and no transparency
PNG or High-quality JPEG
The system will apply a circular mask. 
Do not upload a circular icon.
If your icon is designed with a white or light background, a hairline stroke will be added for display on the App Store.
Before uploading your icon in iTunes Connect, get more details on designing icons for Apple Watch from the Apple Watch Human Interface Guidelines.*

***Icon Sizes**
Home screen icons are circular and Table 20-1 lists the appropriate diameter (in pixels) and the usage for each icon. Create all of these image resources as @2x images. (Note that Xcode lists icon sizes in points.)
Table 20-1Icon sizes for WatchKit app on Apple Watch

```
Asset              | Notification Center icon | Long-Look notification icon | Home Screen icon | Short-Look icon
------------------ | ------------------------ | --------------------------- | ---------------- | ---------------
Apple Watch (38mm) | 48 pixels                | 80 pixels                   | 80 pixels        | 172 pixels
Apple Watch (42mm) | 55 pixels                | 88 pixels                   | 80 pixels        | 196 pixels
```

In addition to the icons used by your WatchKit app, the Apple Watch app running on the user’s iPhone needs icons to represent your app. Table 20-2 lists the sizes (in pixels) for these icon resources. Create these image resources at the indicated resolution. (Note that Xcode lists icon sizes in points.)
Table 20-2Icon sizes for use by Apple Watch app on iPhone

```
Asset | App icon
----- | ---------
@2x   | 58 pixels
@3x   | 87 pixels
```

Create your icons as full-bleed square images using the given dimensions. The system applies the circular mask automatically.
Use the PNG format for all images and icons. Avoid using interlaced PNGs. You can use PNGs with indexed colors to save space in your image files.
Use the standard bit depth for icons and images. The standard bit depth for icons and images is 24 bits—that is, 8 bits each for red, green, and blue. Icons must not include an alpha channel.*

Comment: I have these icons in my WatchKit app bundle

Comment: See new comments in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The App Store rejected again, but I found out that in the Info.plist for my WatchKit App, there was a row for "Icon files" with one item pointing to a file that did not exist. This overrode the "App Icons Source" for the WatchKit App target. Once removed, the problem was solved. It did not matter how many times I tried to work in Images.xcassets, as long as "Icon files" was there, the icon would never appear on the Apple Watch.

Comment: WOW!!! You solved it!!! Thank you sooooo much ... I've wanted to release a watch app since March 2015 ... off an on trying to solve this icon issue; repeatedly being rejected by Apple :/ ... following all of the above suggestions was not enough; I Needed to delete the "Icon files" from the info.plist

Answer (score 0):

If your WatchKit App is configured as described in the answers above and your AppIcon still doesn't appear on your Apple Watch, try:

1. Сleaning your build (choose Product/Clean from the Xcode menu).
2. Еurning off your iPhone (e.g. press/hold power button until red slider appears, then swipe right).
3. Turning off your Apple Watch.
4. Turning on your iPhone and waiting for the home screen to appear.
5. Turning on your Apple Watch.

This did the trick for me. My AppIcon was configured as described in the answers above and initially appeared on my Apple Watch throughout development of my app, but once I began testing certain conditions that required me to uninstall/reinstall my app, the App Icon stopped appearing on my Watch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a correctly formatted AppIcon.appiconset. The easiest way to achieve this is to upload your 1024x1024px image to http://makeappicon.com, from which you can download a fully formatted set that includes the AppIcon.appiconset. Be sure to tick the box to include WatchOS icons in the set. (I have no connection with this website.)

By dragging and dropping this into an Assets.xcassets group in your project, you will import all of the require icon sizes which will already be correctly set for each of the various uses.

Ensure that in your Project application target that under `Build Settings` > `Asset Catalog Compiler - Options` > `Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name` the name is set to AppIcon. You should see the app icons reflected in various menus in Xcode immediately. You may need to do a clean of the build folder first before you see this in the Simulators.